# Reading From Cloud Firestore - Items Briefly Null

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am reading data from Firebase Cloud Firestore and populating them into my UI. Below is my data structure:

[image]

Below is my code to read the data from the Cloud Firestore and populate the UI. I am noticing that for my `TextView`, the item is briefly null before it displays the "Test Q 2." Am I reading data incorrectly? After a split second, the `TextView` populates the question from Firebase, but I find it odd that it is briefly null and the null is visible in the UI:

```
    mStoreBaseRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    mStoreSelectedPollRef = mStoreBaseRef.collection(POLL_LABEL).document(pollID);
    mStoreSelectedPollRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            Poll selectedPoll = documentSnapshot.toObject(Poll.class);
            String pollQuestion = selectedPoll.getQuestion();
            mPollQuestion.setText(pollQuestion);
            mPollQuestion.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously. Depending on your connection speed and the state, it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available.

So the brief time before the poll is populated is the expected behavior. If this is confusing for your users, you might want to populate it with good default values, or show a "loading, please wait" type message.

Comment: Thanks Frank, it is a bit odd as I did not notice it with the realtime database, only now after I have migrated to Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Both databases work the same, so have this behavior. But it could definitely be that the delay is different between them.

Comment: Frank - I realized it was a mistake on my end as I was reading from both the realtime database and Cloud Firestore, with the realtime database being null since I am migrating. Therefore, my UI views were briefly null as well.

Comment: Along those lines - given that Cloud Firestore is in Beta, do you see it fit to continue writing to the database and Firestore concurrently? It would be the same data, just written to both databases.

Comment: Yup, sounds good to me. I've been meaning to update some apps to use parallel writes, either from the app code or through Cloud Functions.